Is maya considered an obstacle to liberation by Vaishnavites?
Vaishnavites certainly accept that maya exists - Vishnu-maya is said to delude Siva when he was overcome by desire for Mohini.
The path to liberation for Vaishnavites is bhakti and surrender to a form of Vishnu (Vishnu, Krisha, Rama et al).
Do they consider Maya an obstacle to achieving liberation?

Short Answer: Yes, however there isn't a separate endeavor to become free from Maya as She is the energy of Krishna and He has explained in the below verse that this would be दुरत्यया (duratyayA) or difficult, rather the goal is to always remember Krishna and surrender unto Him, and Maya would automatically vanish.
Long Answer: In the Bhagavad Gita 7.14, Lord Krishna has said:

दैवी ह्येषा गुणमयी मम माया दुरत्यया । मामेव ये प्रपद्यन्ते मायामेतां
तरन्ति ते ॥ १४ ॥
daivī hy eṣā guṇa-mayī mama māyā duratyayā mām eva ye prapadyante
māyām etāṁ taranti te
This divine energy of Mine, consisting of the three modes of material
nature, is difficult to overcome. But those who have surrendered unto
Me can easily cross beyond it.
The illusory potency of the Supreme Lord is duratyayā; it is
impossible to escape without the direct mercy of Kṛṣṇa (mām eva ye
prapadyante māyām etāṁ taranti te). The example may be given that when
the sun is covered by clouds, no man-made apparatus can remove them
from the sky, but the sun itself, which created the clouds, can
immediately burn away the cloudy covering and reveal itself.
Similarly, when we become covered by the illusory potency of the Lord
we identify with our temporary material body, and thus we are always
in fear and anxiety. But when we surrender to the Lord Himself, He can
immediately free us from this illusion.

In the Chaitanya Charitamrita 22.31, Krishna is compared to sunshine and Maya to darkness to illustrate that they cannot co-exist.

kṛṣṇa — sūrya-sama; māyā haya andhakāra yāhāṅ kṛṣṇa, tāhāṅ nāhi māyāra
adhikāra
“Kṛṣṇa is compared to sunshine, and māyā is compared to darkness.
Wherever there is sunshine, there cannot be darkness. As soon as one
takes to Kṛṣṇa consciousness, the darkness of illusion (the influence
of the external energy) will immediately vanish.

In Sri Prema Vivarta, it is said that living entities are seized by Maya the moment they forget Krishna and desire enjoyment separately.

kṛṣṇa-bahirmukha hañā bhoga vāñchhā kare nikaṭastha māyā tāre jāpaṭiyā
dhare
When souls become averse to Kṛṣṇa and desire enjoyment, nearby Māyā
seizes them.


piśachī pāile yena mati-chchhanna haya māyā-grasta jīvera haya se
bhāva udaya
When someone is possessed by a ghost, they become bewildered. This
condition overtakes souls bound by Māyā.


“āmi nitya kṛṣṇa-dāsa” ei kathā bhule māyāra naphara hañā chira-dina
bule
Forgetting, “I am an eternal servant of Kṛṣṇa”, souls become slaves
of Māyā and wander indefinitely.


kabhu rājā kabhu prajā kabhu vipra śūdra kabhu duḥkhī kabhu sukhī
kabhu kīṭa kṣudra
They are sometimes kings, and sometimes subjects; sometimes brahmiṇs,
and sometimes sudras; sometimes sad, sometimes happy, and sometimes
insignificant ants.


kabhu svarge, kabhu martye, narake vā kabhu kabhu deva, kabhu daitya,
kabhu dāsa prabhu
They are sometimes in heaven, sometimes on earth, and sometimes in
hell; sometimes gods, and sometimes demons; sometimes servants, and
sometimes master.


Suppose maya makes a person reject Krishna.  Since only devotion to Krishna can remove maya - we are in a circular logic situation, right? @harihara

In the Gita, Krishna has said 'mama maya duratyaya' which means "My maya is difficult to overcome" which means that maya is subordinate to Him. Hence, Krishna's remembrance through authorized practices described in the scriptures such as Japa, Shravana, Kirtana, etc. invokes His direct mercy and presence. As maya is Krishna's bahiranga-shakti, she withdraws her influence from those who constantly remember Her Lord.
